# reading files in another directory and passing as input

Tags: python

If I am in the directory `~/a/b/c/d`. I want a program called `hithere.py` and in that program I want to pass some input that is found in file `hi.txt` and is located in directory b. How would I do so?

I tried `f = open("~/a/b/hi.txt","r")` but I get the error `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tilde is bash stuff](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) - you can't use it without bash. So try something like

```
f = open("../../hi.txt","r")
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser), as python doesn't automatically expand paths, so try this:

```
import os

f = open(os.path.expanduser('~/a/b/hi.txt'), 'r')
```